# Trap the JS error of child window using onerror on parent page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload, onerror

I am having a issue with IE, when I open a child window using javascript and attach onerror event on child window I am not getting JS error caught in OnLoad of child window. Below code is working fine in FF.
here is code example:

**Parent Page**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openpage()
{
    console.log('opening');
    var w = window.open('demo2.html', '_blank');
    //without setTimeout onerror is not working
    setTimeout(function(){w.onerror = function(msg, file, line) { alert(msg); };}, 3000)
    //w.onerror = function(msg, file, line) { alert(msg); };
}
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="openpage()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Child Page code (demo2.html):**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
//function with error
function fun(var1,var2){aler(var1);}
</script>
</head>
    <body onload="fun(2,3)">
        <input type="button" onclick="fun(2,3)" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Please suggest a way to capture the JS error generated on child page If above way is not valid/correct.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: If you debug using the F12 tools, is an exception thrown when your page loads? Are you running from a website or off your local disk?

Comment: Yes exception is thrown and I can see it in console with F12 tool. I tried it on both i.e. website hosted in IIS and from local disk. Same code is working fine with Firefox, issue is only with IE, I tried with version 7 and above.

Comment: appreciate any further